# Is it possible to implement user accounts for RStudio?

Tags: rstudio, user-accounts

Is there a possibility to create user accounts for RStudio? Like e.g. for office products users can create accounts with which they are logged in for all office applications. The reason I ask is to see whether it is possible to see and track which users open certain R files (for work space security) and limit access for users to certain files. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this what are you looking for?
https://docs.rstudio.com/connect/admin/user-management.html

Comment: If I understand correctly, Rstudio Connect manages the access to whatever work is created via a R script (Shiny app, markdown document etc.) but it doesn't show/restrict which person opens/modifies .R scripts. I meant a function like e.g. in word - when someone is logged into his Microsoft account and uses word, the word session is run under his Microsoft account. Is there some function like that for the RStudio IDE? Or does RStudio Connect provide this function as well?